# Adding sum of the nested dictionary values using keys from the list

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I was creating a war game and I have this dictionary of weapons and the damage they do on another type of troops.

also, I have a list which has the keys from the dictionary stored in it.

```
weapon_specs = {
 'rifle': {'air': 1, 'ground': 2, 'human': 5},
 'pistol': {'air': 0, 'ground': 1, 'human': 3},
 'rpg': {'air': 5, 'ground': 5, 'human': 3},
 'warhead': {'air': 10, 'ground': 10, 'human': 10},
 'machine gun': {'air': 3, 'ground': 3, 'human': 10}
}

inv = ['rifle', 'machine gun', 'pistol']
```

I need to get this output:

```
{'air': 4, 'ground': 6, 'human': 18}
```

I tried this :

```
for i in weapon_specs:
  for k in inv:
    if i == k:
        list.update(weapon_specs[k])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
count = Counter()
for counter in [weapon_specs[weapon] for weapon in inv]:
    count += counter
out = dict(count)
```

If you don't want to use `collections` library, you can also do:

```
out = {}
for weapon in inv:
    for k,v in weapon_specs[weapon].items():
        out[k] = out.get(k, 0) + v
```

Output:

```
{'air': 4, 'ground': 6, 'human': 18}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having to import anything. You can just map the dictionary with two loops.

```
out = {'air': 0, 'ground': 0, 'human': 0}

for weapon in inv:
    for k, v in weapon_specs[weapon].items():
        out[k] += v

print(out)
```

Output:

```
{'air': 4, 'ground': 6, 'human': 18}
```

Answer (score 0):

used the counter from collections to add the dictionary values with reference to inv

```
from collections import Counter
weapon_specs = {'rifle': {'air': 1, 'ground': 2, 'human': 5},'pistol': {'air': 0, 'ground': 1, 'human': 3},'rpg': {'air': 5, 'ground': 5, 'human': 3},'warhead': {'air': 10, 'ground': 10, 'human': 10},'machine gun': {'air': 3, 'ground': 3, 'human': 10}}
inv = ['riffle', 'machine gun', 'pistol']
summation = Counter()
for category, values in weapon_specs.items():
    if category in inv:
        summation.update(values)
summation = dict(summation)
print(summation)
```

output:

```
{'air': 4, 'ground': 6, 'human': 18}
```

Answer (score -1):

First take a subset of your dictionary according to your list.
Then use `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
subset = {k: weapon_specs[k] for k in inv}
out = dict(sum((Counter(d) for d in subset.values()), Counter()))
```

**Result**

```
{'air': 4, 'ground': 6, 'human': 18}
```